# Does Windows protect MBR from being overwritten?

Tags: rootkits

I have read [article about TDL/Alureon Rootkit](https://www.darknet.org.uk/2010/11/tdl-aka-alureon-rootkit-now-infecting-64-bit-windows-7-platform/):

> According to research published on Monday by GFI Software, the latest TDL4 installation penetrates 64-bit versions of Windows by bypassing the OS’s kernel mode code signing policy, which is designed to allow drivers to be installed only when they have been digitally signed by a trusted source. The rootkit achieves this feat by attaching itself to the master boot record in a hard drive’s bowels and changing the machine’s boot options.

Does this mean that Windows doesn't protect MBR from being overwritten? Can then any program, including malware/rootkit, running with administrator privileges just overwrite MBR and simply bypass driver signing enforcement?

Thanks for any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

An administrative/SYSTEM user has complete access to the system, and can make changes to disk partitions, etc. Also, tools exist for Windows which can modify the MBR to point to a different bootloader. So I'd say, no, there is nothing protecting it.

The question makes it sound like a big deal that "any program" running with administrator privileges can overwrite the MBR. A process with SYSTEM privileges can do whatever it wants. However, that is the standard threat model; if someone else runs code on your computer, it's not your computer anymore.

Comment: Doesn't Windows use its TPM to verify it?

Comment: @forest I didn't think that applied to MBR schemes, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Ah yeah you're right, MBR only works with CSM/BIOS, not UEFI.

Answer (score 1):

Defending MBR from changes may be a difficult task. But there's a way of *warning* the user that the OS Windows loader file have been modified.

Starting from Windows 6.1 there's a built in possibility of using `Require Signature Check` or `INTEGRITYCHECK`.
This tool can check if the file was modified and even prevent OS loading. E.g. if you would use EasyBCD software to edit Windows loader code from a guest OS you may be notified about those changes during the next loading with 0xc0000428 status code.

[image]

This security may be applied not only for a loader files but for any DLL that implements kernel-mode code.

The mentioning about this technique can also be investigated in more details in this [book source](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ifQPC86G66sC&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=integritycheck+winload&source=bl&ots=WT_8nejtK8&sig=6uwhBdOOxu7-mtNT9kyI31rscEw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo8tSE3NjaAhUQyaYKHQ_yC8kQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=integrity%20check&f=false).